# Fast Load in Data Flow task generates SQL table of excessive size

Tags: sql-server, ssis

For context, I have an SQL Server with multiple tables that are populated from text files.  The text files are generated from excel processes, and a given table will be built from multiple text files, as each state or region has its own text files.  So for example we'll have a REVENUES table built from AR REVENUES.txt, CA REVENUES.txt, MI REVENUES.txt, etc.

Our current process involves using SSIS packages to drop the existing tables, then run a foreach loop enumerator over the files we want with a data flow task to upload those files to our server.  This works reasonably well for the most part.

However, one table, let's call it Table A, is huge.  The table is 3-4 thousand rows, 130 columns, and according to the table properties window, the SSMS report on the db, and the db sys tables, Table A was 62,000 MB in size.  I tried dropping the table and regenerating it via the SSIS package, still 62,000 MB.  Eventually I changed the Data Flow Task from using a Fast Load to a regular Table or View, and Table A is 4.12 MB.

The only thing that I changed was the use of Fast Load to regular slow load in the Data Flow task, the data being uploaded was the same, Table A was the same size in terms of data, rows, and columns.  It just became 15,000 times smaller.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Impossible to say at this point. Use Fast load and script the table definition. Then redo without and see if you get the same definition. If schema remains the same, it could be that table A is [a heap and it doesn't give back space until you truncate](https://sqlstudies.com/2014/08/25/the-amazing-never-shrinking-heap/)

Comment: Table A is a heap! What do you mean by giving back space until it's truncated?